# UIActivityController sharing to Microsoft Teams cuts off the modal

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, microsoft-teams, ios-sharesheet

[Sharing on teams bugs out modal like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7glf.jpg)

I have implemented UIActivityController where I am sharing an image along with a link but excluding image when sharing it to any app and using the image just for saving it to camera roll. When I try to share to Microsoft Teams, this is what I could see which happens randomly (inconsistent). What could be the cause of this issue? Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
            present(activityView, animated: true) {
            }
        } else {
            // Change Rect to position Popover
            popup = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: activityView)
            popup.present(from: CGRect(x: view.frame.size.width / 2, y: view.frame.size.width / 2, width: 100, height: 100), in: view, permittedArrowDirections: .any, animated: true)
        }
```

Comment: This is happening on phone (iPhone 11, iPhone 8 Plus, iPhone 11 Max Pro) with the same present code, very rarely and stops after sometime